# PHP Laravel orderby not working if using `count`

Tags: php, laravel

I want to sort/order my data by its `release_date` but I get an error I don't understand:

In my Controller I have:

```
public function index() {
    $releases = Release::orderBy('release_date', 'desc');
    return view('pages.index')->with('releases', $releases);
}
```

and in my view file I have this:

```
@if (count($releases) > 0) 
  @foreach ($releases as $release)
    <div>
        <p>{{$release->artist}} - {{$release->album_title}} <span>ReleaseDate: {{$release->release_date}}</span></p>
    </div>
  @endforeach
@endif
```

This returns the error:

> count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements
>   Countable

What does this mean? Can someone help me out?

Comment: It means that $releases is not an object or an array...

Comment: You forget `get()` method after `orderBy()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
public function index() 
{
    $releases = Release::orderBy('release_date', 'desc')->get();

    return view('pages.index')->with('releases', $releases);
}
```

The reason you code wasn't working before is because `orderBy` won't perform the query, it will simply add to it. In this case you need to chain on `get()` at the end in order to perform the query and get the results otherwise you will just get an instance of the query builder.

Comment: @Bhoomipatel Thanks for giving your answer but if you can please always provide an explanation to why the code will work. I have added an explanation to your answer but please feel to add to it or update it as you see fit.

Comment: Thanku sir for providing the explanation to this answers, i will always provide explanation to answers.@RossWilson

Answer (score 0):

Change Controller

```
public function index() {
    $releases = Release::orderBy('release_date', 'desc')->get();
    return view('pages.index',compact('releases');
}
```

change View

```
@if ($releases->count() > 0) 
  @foreach ($releases as $release)
    <div>
        <p>{{$release->artist}} - {{$release->album_title}} <span>ReleaseDate: {{$release->release_date}}</span></p>
    </div>
  @endforeach
@endif
```